# Place Binance Future Order using python-binance wrapper. Error: APIError(code=-1102): Mandatory parameter '5e-05' was not sent

Tags: python, bots, binance, binance-api-client

I create future order with mandatory parameters

```
import datetime
from binance.client import Client

client = Client(API_KEY, API_SECRET)
timestamp = datetime.datetime.now().timestamp()

trade = client.futures_create_order(symbol='BTCUSDT', type='LIMIT', timeInForce='GTC', price=48000, side='BUY', quantity=0.00005, timestamp=timestamp )
```

This code gives error:

```
binance.exceptions.BinanceAPIException: APIError(code=-1102): Mandatory parameter '5e-05' was not sent, was empty/null, or malformed.
```

Binance-Doc link: https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/futures/en/#new-order-trade

Comment: In [docs](https://python-binance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/account.html#id2) they send floats as strings and use enums instead of string constants. Did you try it?

Comment: @StanislavIvanov thank you for your suggestion. I tried that way also. but not worked.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was I'm not setting my price and quantity to a supported precision value.
So 1st I get the price precision and quantity precision data and then convert my price and quantity according to that precision

```
symbol = 'FTMUSDT'
price = 1.38
quantity = 4.5

for info in info['symbols']:
    if info['pair'] == symbol:
        pricePrecision = info['pricePrecision']
        quantityPrecision = info['quantityPrecision']

final_price = "{:0.0{}f}".format(price, pricePrecision)
final_quantity = "{:0.0{}f}".format(quantity, quantityPrecision)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try "LONG" instead of "BUY" at the parameters of

```
futures_create_order()
```

function.

Comment: nope. parameter 'side' must be "BUY" or "SELL".
'positionSide' should be "BOTH", "LONG", "SHORT".
But for future LIMIT order we don't need to pass 'positionSide'. It has a default value ("BOTH")